# Unmarshalling XML from a secure URL in Java

Tags: java, url, basic-authentication

Im trying to reach a XML file behind a secure url. I want to unmarshall the file from a url based on a XSD binding I already have. Here is my method.

```
public void urlTest(String url){
    URLConnection connection = null;
    JAXBContext jc;

    try {
        String userPassword = username + ":" + password;
        String encoding = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(userPassword.getBytes());  
        URL add = new URL(this.url);            
        connection = add.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);  
        connection.connect();

        jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("XML");
        Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();            
        Object o = u.unmarshal(connection.getURL());

        System.out.println("Complete");

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(UrlDownload.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (JAXBException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(UrlDownload.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } 
}
```

I get an 401 server error from this. The username and password I pass are correct. Perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: Nothing immediate comes to mind. I'd check what's going out, with tcpdump if it's not encrypted, some stunnel trickery if it is. I'm sure others could suggest something more sophisticated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after quick scan it looks liek you are providing an URL to the unmarshaller, not the connection with Authorization.

Comment: I changed the code to the following...

Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();                        
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

But the error I get is

javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.]
            Object o = u.unmarshal(inputStream);

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
Object o = u.unmarshal(connection.getURL());
```

You're fetching the URl from the connection that you've already opened, and passing that to the Unmarshaller, which will then open it's *own* connection, which will fail.

You need to give the Unmarshaller the `InputStream` from the connection that you just opened, e.g.

```
InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
Object o = u.unmarshal(inputStream);
```

and then before you exit the method:

```
inputStream.close();
```

Comment: Hi, 

I made adjustments to the code but got an error on the

Object o = u.unmarshal(inputStream);

Error message

SCHWERWIEGEND: null
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.]

Any ideas?

Comment: Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();                       `enter code here` 
        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        Object o = u.unmarshal(inputStream);
but this gives the following error

        SCHWERWIEGEND: null
        javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
        - with linked exception:
        [org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.]
Any ideas?